# installing SSDT

Tags: sql-server, ssdt

I am preparing the MCSA 70-763 exam. I need to install the SSDT to deploy my pacakges into sql server. I am beginner and have 0 experience with VS and SSDT.
When I tried to install SSDT from Sql server installation center the installation failed and I understand nothing in the journal file which is suppose to contain the problem.

can anyone help me to debug this step? Tanks in advance

Here is the content of the journal file:

```
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_SSDTPOSTINSTALL' to value 'C:\Users\ahmad\AppData\Local\Temp\sql_SSDT_1400_20161217131607_23_SSDTPOSTINSTALL_rollback.log'
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_SSDTPOSTINSTALL' to value 'C:\Users\ahmad\AppData\Local\Temp\sql_SSDT_1400_20161217131607_23_SSDTPOSTINSTALL.log'
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: DEV14ISOSHELL, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: DEV14ISOSHELLLP, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: DEV14INTSHELLADDITIONAL, state: Present, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: DEV14INTSHELLADDITIONALLP, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: DotNet46, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: DotNet46LangPack, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: adalsql13X86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: adalsql13X64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: SQLDOM13X86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: SQLDOM13X64, state: Obsolete, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: TSQLLANGSVC13X86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: TSQLLANGSVC13X64, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: SQLLOCALDBX64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: SQLLOCALDBX32, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: SQLCLRTYPES13X86, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: SQLCLRTYPES13X64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: SQLSMO13X86, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: SQLSMO13X64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: SQLNCLIX86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: SQLNCLIX64, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: SSDTEXTERNALS13, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: SSDT14, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: SQLASADOMD, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: SQLASOLEDB, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: SQLASOLEDBX64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: SQLAMO, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: CommonAzureTools, state: Obsolete, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: CommonAzureTools.Lang, state: Obsolete, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: CommonAzureTools.VwdExpress, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: CommonAzureTools.VwdExpress.Lang, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: CommonAzureTools.WdExpress, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: CommonAzureTools.WdExpress.Lang, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: VSTALS2015, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: VSTASetup2015, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: VCRedist2010, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: SSISOneDesigner2012, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: SSISOneDesigner2014, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: AMO2012, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: AMO2014, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: SSDTAS, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: SSDTRS, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: SSDTIS, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Planned package: SSDTPOSTINSTALL, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Apply begin
[1F38:24C0][2016-12-17T13:24:43]: Creating a system restore point.
[1F38:24C0][2016-12-17T13:24:44]: Created a system restore point.
[1F38:24C0][2016-12-17T13:24:46]: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\ahmad\AppData\Local\Temp\{1989056c-b3ed-4ff8-8191-fdc4b19bd083}\.be\SSDTSetup.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{1989056c-b3ed-4ff8-8191-fdc4b19bd083}\SSDTSetup.exe'
[1F38:24C0][2016-12-17T13:24:46]: Registering bundle dependency provider: {1989056c-b3ed-4ff8-8191-fdc4b19bd083}, version: 14.0.61021.0
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:24:46]: Prompt for source of package: DEV14ISOSHELLLP, payload: DEV14ISOSHELLLP, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\payload\x86\vs_isoshellLP.exe
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:24:46]: Acquiring package: DEV14ISOSHELLLP, payload: DEV14ISOSHELLLP, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=715686&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:25:06]: Verified acquired payload: DEV14ISOSHELLLP at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\DEV14ISOSHELLLP, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\EC32B2F1C134B1E659453D67431ACD3BA21A3B9E\payload\x86\vs_isoshellLP.exe.
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:06]: Prompt for source of package: DEV14INTSHELLADDITIONALLP, payload: DEV14INTSHELLADDITIONALLP, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\payload\x86\vs_intshelladditionalLP.exe
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:06]: Acquiring package: DEV14INTSHELLADDITIONALLP, payload: DEV14INTSHELLADDITIONALLP, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=715684&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:25:07]: Verified acquired payload: DEV14INTSHELLADDITIONALLP at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\DEV14INTSHELLADDITIONALLP, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\1180C805CB38FE1D71CB97149D322058364D1AD6\payload\x86\vs_intshelladditionalLP.exe.
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:07]: Prompt for source of package: adalsql13X64, payload: adalsql13X64, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\payload\x64\adalsql.msi
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:07]: Acquiring package: adalsql13X64, payload: adalsql13X64, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817285&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:25:08]: Verified acquired payload: adalsql13X64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\adalsql13X64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{10BD561E-12B5-4E3D-B982-DF43879E7DAC}v13.0.1601.5\payload\x64\adalsql.msi.
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:08]: Prompt for source of package: SQLLOCALDBX64, payload: SQLLOCALDBX64, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\payload\x64\SqlLocalDB.msi
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:08]: Acquiring package: SQLLOCALDBX64, payload: SQLLOCALDBX64, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=824665&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:25:19]: Verified acquired payload: SQLLOCALDBX64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\SQLLOCALDBX64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{905B7F07-5B7A-4847-BA80-59AC8A1B7DFE}v13.0.2151.0\payload\x64\SqlLocalDB.msi.
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:19]: Prompt for source of package: SQLCLRTYPES13X86, payload: SQLCLRTYPES13X86, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\payload\x86\SQLSysClrTypes.msi
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:19]: Acquiring package: SQLCLRTYPES13X86, payload: SQLCLRTYPES13X86, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817274&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:25:20]: Verified acquired payload: SQLCLRTYPES13X86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\SQLCLRTYPES13X86, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{205E7FEB-E47C-4D50-821E-9A42DF2E8C29}v13.0.1601.5\payload\x86\SQLSysClrTypes.msi.
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:20]: Prompt for source of package: SQLCLRTYPES13X64, payload: SQLCLRTYPES13X64, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\payload\x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:20]: Acquiring package: SQLCLRTYPES13X64, payload: SQLCLRTYPES13X64, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817290&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:25:22]: Verified acquired payload: SQLCLRTYPES13X64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\SQLCLRTYPES13X64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{1D2AE7A5-78A9-41D4-9454-5DFFEDC8FAF3}v13.0.1601.5\payload\x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi.
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:22]: Prompt for source of package: SQLSMO13X86, payload: SQLSMO13X86, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\payload\x86\SharedManagementObjects.msi
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:22]: Acquiring package: SQLSMO13X86, payload: SQLSMO13X86, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817265&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:25:24]: Verified acquired payload: SQLSMO13X86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\SQLSMO13X86, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{AD9D2D2F-E04F-46EF-9416-2F04AD04A56A}v13.0.1601.5\payload\x86\SharedManagementObjects.msi.
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:24]: Prompt for source of package: SQLSMO13X64, payload: SQLSMO13X64, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\payload\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:24]: Acquiring package: SQLSMO13X64, payload: SQLSMO13X64, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817286&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:25:26]: Verified acquired payload: SQLSMO13X64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\SQLSMO13X64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{B66A510A-C6BE-4E85-A2B7-28C66A830B92}v13.0.1601.5\payload\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi.
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:26]: Prompt for source of package: SSDTEXTERNALS13, payload: SSDTEXTERNALS13, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\payload\x86\SSDTDBSvcExternals.msi
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:26]: Acquiring package: SSDTEXTERNALS13, payload: SSDTEXTERNALS13, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817276&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:25:27]: Verified acquired payload: SSDTEXTERNALS13 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\SSDTEXTERNALS13, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{33689273-0F4C-40AD-AEFB-59583F08767D}v13.0.1601.5\payload\x86\SSDTDBSvcExternals.msi.
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:27]: Prompt for source of package: SSDT14, payload: SSDT14, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\ssdt\x86\SSDT.msi
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:27]: Acquiring package: SSDT14, payload: SSDT14, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=832314&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:25:31]: Verified acquired payload: SSDT14 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\SSDT14, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{FD56160B-E437-4B1C-9C99-1FA6EFFFE9B8}v14.0.61021.0\ssdt\x86\SSDT.msi.
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:31]: Prompt for source of package: SQLASADOMD, payload: SQLASADOMD, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\payload\x86\SQL_AS_ADOMD.msi
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:31]: Acquiring package: SQLASADOMD, payload: SQLASADOMD, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:25:32]: Verified acquired payload: SQLASADOMD at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\SQLASADOMD, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{5E406E56-EC13-49FC-86EF-AD0352AE285C}v13.0.1601.5\payload\x86\SQL_AS_ADOMD.msi.
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:32]: Prompt for source of package: SQLASOLEDB, payload: SQLASOLEDB, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\payload\x86\SQL_AS_OLEDB.msi
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:32]: Acquiring package: SQLASOLEDB, payload: SQLASOLEDB, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=832060&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:25:39]: Verified acquired payload: SQLASOLEDB at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\SQLASOLEDB, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{FBF90269-D088-471F-8E13-3201234086D8}v13.0.1601.5\payload\x86\SQL_AS_OLEDB.msi.
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:39]: Prompt for source of package: SQLASOLEDBX64, payload: SQLASOLEDBX64, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\payload\x64\SQL_AS_OLEDB.msi
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:39]: Acquiring package: SQLASOLEDBX64, payload: SQLASOLEDBX64, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=832048&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:25:52]: Verified acquired payload: SQLASOLEDBX64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\SQLASOLEDBX64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{A2C0AED8-4C6F-4C87-984A-17EEEFDC710C}v13.0.1601.5\payload\x64\SQL_AS_OLEDB.msi.
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:52]: Prompt for source of package: SQLAMO, payload: SQLAMO, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\payload\x86\SQL_AS_AMO.msi
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:52]: Acquiring package: SQLAMO, payload: SQLAMO, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817267&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:25:54]: Verified acquired payload: SQLAMO at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\SQLAMO, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{B6EE5915-E1E6-4D57-8593-433497CC92C5}v13.0.1601.5\payload\x86\SQL_AS_AMO.msi.
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:54]: Prompt for source of package: VSTALS2015, payload: VSTALS2015, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\payload\x86\vsta_ls.exe
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:54]: Acquiring package: VSTALS2015, payload: VSTALS2015, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=832089&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:25:58]: Verified acquired payload: VSTALS2015 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\VSTALS2015, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\A64726864CA02FD2A1ADCFBCF782C5FA5F1305C7\payload\x86\vsta_ls.exe.
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:58]: Prompt for source of package: VSTASetup2015, payload: VSTASetup2015, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\payload\x86\vsta_setup.exe
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:25:58]: Acquiring package: VSTASetup2015, payload: VSTASetup2015, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817280&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:26:00]: Verified acquired payload: VSTASetup2015 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\VSTASetup2015, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\5E6157D16EC044A823B2FD2C030ED6DECD2E997E\payload\x86\vsta_setup.exe.
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:26:00]: Prompt for source of package: SSISOneDesigner2012, payload: SSISOneDesigner2012, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\payload\x86\SSISOneDesigner2012.msi
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:26:00]: Acquiring package: SSISOneDesigner2012, payload: SSISOneDesigner2012, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817279&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:26:04]: Verified acquired payload: SSISOneDesigner2012 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\SSISOneDesigner2012, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{AA0A8863-A97C-439D-AADD-02F14DD80182}v11.3.6520.8\payload\x86\SSISOneDesigner2012.msi.
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:26:04]: Prompt for source of package: SSISOneDesigner2014, payload: SSISOneDesigner2014, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\payload\x86\SSISOneDesigner2014.msi
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:26:04]: Acquiring package: SSISOneDesigner2014, payload: SSISOneDesigner2014, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817281&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:26:09]: Verified acquired payload: SSISOneDesigner2014 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\SSISOneDesigner2014, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{EC186432-9867-4053-A9C1-DF225EA4F31E}v12.1.4448.0\payload\x86\SSISOneDesigner2014.msi.
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:26:09]: Prompt for source of package: AMO2012, payload: AMO2012, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\payload\x86\SQL_AS_AMO2012.msi
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:26:09]: Acquiring package: AMO2012, payload: AMO2012, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817268&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:26:10]: Verified acquired payload: AMO2012 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\AMO2012, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{372412F8-B6DF-472F-8303-A1052451A25A}v11.3.6020.0\payload\x86\SQL_AS_AMO2012.msi.
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:26:10]: Prompt for source of package: AMO2014, payload: AMO2014, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\payload\x86\SQL_AS_AMO2014.msi
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:26:10]: Acquiring package: AMO2014, payload: AMO2014, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817269&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:26:11]: Verified acquired payload: AMO2014 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\AMO2014, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{DE1A021F-6BB9-4458-9742-263CD4D19133}v12.1.4100.1\payload\x86\SQL_AS_AMO2014.msi.
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:26:11]: Prompt for source of package: SSDTAS, payload: SSDTAS, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\payload\x86\SSDTAS.msi
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:26:11]: Acquiring package: SSDTAS, payload: SSDTAS, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=832079&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:26:41]: Verified acquired payload: SSDTAS at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\SSDTAS, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{C8916E91-CC65-4B7B-9D4D-E6889E23A46C}v13.0.1701.8\payload\x86\SSDTAS.msi.
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:26:41]: Prompt for source of package: SSDTRS, payload: SSDTRS, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\payload\x86\SSDTRS.msi
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:26:41]: Acquiring package: SSDTRS, payload: SSDTRS, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=832067&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:26:50]: Verified acquired payload: SSDTRS at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\SSDTRS, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{0D76AA81-4E6D-4714-83AB-0D061DEBDF4F}v13.0.1701.8\payload\x86\SSDTRS.msi.
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:26:50]: Prompt for source of package: SSDTIS, payload: SSDTIS, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\payload\x86\SSDTIS.msi
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:26:50]: Acquiring package: SSDTIS, payload: SSDTIS, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=832099&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:27:02]: Verified acquired payload: SSDTIS at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\SSDTIS, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7B54C177-AA22-446F-97C8-D2974098E016}v13.0.2165.0\payload\x86\SSDTIS.msi.
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:27:02]: Prompt for source of package: SSDTPOSTINSTALL, payload: SSDTPOSTINSTALL, path: C:\Users\ahmad\Downloads\payload\x86\SSDTPostInstall.msi
[1920:2C20][2016-12-17T13:27:02]: Acquiring package: SSDTPOSTINSTALL, payload: SSDTPOSTINSTALL, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817262&clcid=0x40c
[1F38:0E9C][2016-12-17T13:27:02]: Verified acquired payload: SSDTPOSTINSTALL at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\SSDTPOSTINSTALL, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{4662BC61-4563-4787-8794-8C120986BD4E}v14.0.61021.0\payload\x86\SSDTPostInstall.msi.
[1F38:24C0][2016-12-17T13:27:02]: Applying execute package: DEV14ISOSHELLLP, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\EC32B2F1C134B1E659453D67431ACD3BA21A3B9E\payload\x86\vs_isoshellLP.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\EC32B2F1C134B1E659453D67431ACD3BA21A3B9E\payload\x86\vs_isoshellLP.exe" /q /norestart'
[1F38:24C0][2016-12-17T13:27:24]: Error 0x80044000: Process returned error: 0x80044000
[1F38:24C0][2016-12-17T13:27:24]: Error 0x80044000: Failed to execute EXE package.
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:27:24]: Error 0x80044000: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:27:24]: Applied execute package: DEV14ISOSHELLLP, result: 0x80044000, restart: None
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:27:24]: Error 0x80044000: Failed to execute EXE package.
[1F38:24C0][2016-12-17T13:27:24]: Removing cached package: DEV14ISOSHELLLP, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\EC32B2F1C134B1E659453D67431ACD3BA21A3B9E\
[1F38:24C0][2016-12-17T13:27:24]: Removed bundle dependency provider: {1989056c-b3ed-4ff8-8191-fdc4b19bd083}
[1F38:24C0][2016-12-17T13:27:24]: Removing cached bundle: {1989056c-b3ed-4ff8-8191-fdc4b19bd083}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{1989056c-b3ed-4ff8-8191-fdc4b19bd083}\
[1920:0420][2016-12-17T13:27:25]: Apply complete, result: 0x80044000, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error occurs when trying to install `vs_isoshellLP.exe`, the Visual Studio Shell with the error code `0x80044000`. More about: [Blocking Condition 0x80044000](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2014/04/17/error-in-installation-log-for-visual-studio-2013-update-2-rc-can-be-misleading/).

What version of **Windows** are you running?

Do you have any versions of Visual Studio already installed?

1. Make sure that your **Windows Updates** are up to date.
2. Run **`sfc /scannow`** to repair system files.

   - [TechNet - System File Checker (sfc)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491008.aspx)
   - [How to use SFC /Scannow](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-use-sfc-scannow-to-repair-windows-system-files-2626161)
3. Confirm that you have **[Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653)** installed.
4. Try installing Visual Studio 2015 first, which [solved this person's error](http://blog.jpries.com/2015/08/04/windows-10-upgrade-part-4-cannot-install-ssdt-bi-install-error/).

   - Get [Visual Studio Community Edition 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) if you dont have your own version.
   - If you have errors trying to install Visual Studio 2015 check here: [Common issues in Visual Studio 2015 setup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3039361).
   - If you already have Visual Studio 2015 installed try to [repair your current installation of Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx#Anchor_8).
5. I would also be using the **SSDT ISO** to install SSDT which you can get from Step 4 here:  [SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501).

   - For help with ISO files: [How to Mount an ISO image in Windows 7, 8, and 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/mount-an-iso-image-in-windows-vista/).

Comment: SqlZim, I launched the install directly from Visual studio but I checked if there are any updates to do in windows update. There was only one update on reporting services. After launching this update I tried again to install SSDT from Visual studio and it works!! So I don't know if it works because I launch it from VS or because there was an update to do on reporting services.  Thanks for your help